# django template: dot after filter

Tags: django-templates

So I have a list present in the template context and I want to apply random and then access an attribute of the resulting object.
So far, what I've read in the template section of the django documentation, filters always have to come *after* the variable so I understand (even though I tried it anyway) that

```
{{ my_list|random.attribute }}
```

won't work.
Right now I'm using a custom filter to access *attribute*, so I can chain it after any other filter, but what would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) to give the result another name temporarily.